# Using EF 4.4 and not 5.0 with VS2012

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, orm

We move some projects from VS2010 to VS2012 but still using .NET 4.0 and **not** .NET 4.5

When I add an new EDMX, VS2012 use EF 5.0 but I'd like continue to use the version 4.x it's the first point.

Second point the version 5.0, inherit from DbContext and not ObjectContext like version 4.x. With the version 5.0 I don't see any way to pass the connection string as parameter.

How can I use version 4.x in VS2012, with the same EDMX designer behavior ?

Thanks,

Comment: EF 4.4 is the .NET 4 separate EntityFramework.dll assembly, which also contains `DbContext`. `ObjectContext` is part of the core `System.Data.Entity.dll` assembly. Do you only want to use the latter? If so, that's EF 4.0, not 4.4.

Comment: @hvd The point is how generate EDMX version 4 from VS2012 and not EF 5 ?

Comment: The EDMX version is 2.0, not 4, not 5, and adding an EDMX to a .NET 4 project adds a reference to EF 4.4, not to EF 5, so it is really not clear to me what your first point is about. The second point (DbContext vs ObjectContext) is clear, I'm just not sure what you're asking beyond that.

Comment: I create an EDMX from VS2012, VS2012 download (without asking me anything) Entity Framework 5 from nuget ( http://nuget.org/packages/entityframework)

Comment: Ah, yes, that's confusing. The EF 5 package contains both EF 5 and EF 4.4. You're getting EF 4.4. Take a look in your project references, click EntityFramework, and check the properties.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you're really getting EF 4.4, not EF 5.0. However, confusingly, EF 4.4 in contained in the NuGet EntityFramework 5.0 package.

For your other question, you can open the EDMX in the designer, restore "Code generation strategy" from "None" to "Default", then in the solution explorer, remove the `.tt` files. Now you'll have your `ObjectContext` again, and if you wish, you can remove the EntityFramework package from your project.

I'm not sure if there's any way to change this default behaviour of adding the NuGet package.

Comment: Is there way to come back to the new version ? (without delete and create EDMX)

Comment: @Kris-I Yes, right-click in the designer, and choose "Add code generation item" (from memory, actual text may be slightly different)